# where can I find make_labels?

Tags: featuretools

I do not find make_labels

I thought it would be part of the independent package utils. But I guess it was part of featuretools.

it featuretools.utils

you just have make_temporal_cutoffs instead. So how do you use that? Waht would be the translation of the example code:

```py
label_times = pd.concat([utils.make_labels(es=instacart_es,
                                           product_name = "Banana",
                                           cutoff_time = pd.Timestamp('March 15, 2015'),
                                           prediction_window = ft.Timedelta("4 weeks"),
                                           training_window = ft.Timedelta("60 days"))
```

Answer (score 0):

found out!

make_label is not part of featuretool but of the example repository

https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-next-purchase